# c# problem accessing remote OPC(da) server

Tags: c#, siemens, opc-da

Opposing to previous assumptions our partner still uses opc da on a Siemens S7-319F 3PN/DP

Now I'm trying to connect to said opc da server on a remote machine.

If I use OPC Scout V10 everything looks fine - but when I try to connect using Siemens' COMDA client or one of their example programs like 21043779_Csharp_OPCClient_RCW_CODE\OpcClientDA_V2

I get errors that finally point to a 0x80070005 E_AccessDenied

- Firewalls are disabled on both systems, Server system is setup for remote access as can be seen in OPC Scout which works locally on the server AND on the remote machine ...

My question is - why is opc scount able to access the opc server and pull various variables while my client software on the same machine and using the same account gets errors ?

What can I do to finally enable the opc communication not only using opc scout ? End result should be read and write access to said opc variables

Comment: If you are running in side Visual Studio you do not have admin privileges unless you create a shortcut and then start VS by right click shortcut and select ran as admin.  If that is not the issue then use a Windows Explorer and see if you can access file from explorer.  If you are an admin use \\server\c$ where dollar sign is admin privileges.  See : https://superuser.com/questions/328461/how-to-access-c-share-in-a-network

Comment: Tried executing outside VS - no change . Full error message is > COM-Objekt of type "System._ComObject" couldn't be converted into interface type "OpcRcw.Da.IOPCServer". This step could not execute since QueryInterface-Call to the Com-Component for the interface with the IID "{39C13A4D-011E-11D0-9675-0020AFD8ADB3}" failed with the following error (Exception on HRESULT>: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).<

Answer (score 1):

you can read this guide i think it'll help you :-

[kepware quickstart guide pdf on webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20200919113401/https://www.kepware.com/getattachment/04042e47-c690-467c-a931-a1ca126575db/Remote-OPC-DA-Quick-Start-Guide-DCOM.pdf)